# How to construct a list of keys from a Map?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to construct a list of keys from a `Map`. This is what I do:

```
Map.fold (fun state key value -> state::value) [] [("one", 1); ("two", 2)]
```

However, the bit `state::value` produces this error:

```
tryout.fs(146,48): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a    
but given a
    'a list
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `map |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map fst |> Seq.toList`

Comment: not sure about Seq.map fst though, where does fst come from?

Comment: It's a built-in [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370480.aspx).

Comment: @Daniel `Map.toSeq` returns a sequence of `KeyValuePair<_>`, so the correct version is
`map |> Seq.map (fun kv -> kv.Key) |> Seq.toList`.

Comment: @EugeneFotin: Nay, the signature is: [`Map<'Key,'T> -> seq<'Key * 'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353481.aspx).

Comment: @Daniel Damn, I've skipped **Map.toSeq**, just iterated over map directly. Your solution looks better.

Comment: Or even: map |> Map.toList |> List.map fst

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others already posted great solutions, so just to answer your question and explain what is wrong with your code - since you're using `Map.fold` I assume that your data source is actually a map and not a list:

```
let sample = Map.ofSeq [("one", 1); ("two", 2)]
```

Here is your original solution and one that works side-by-side:

```
// Original version - attempts to add 'state' as the new head of a list 'value'
Map.fold (fun state key value -> state::value) [] sample
// Corrected version - adds 'key' as the new head of a list 'state'
Map.fold (fun state key value -> key::state) [] sample
```

The key thing is that the `::` operator needs to have a value (here `string`) on the left and another list (here `string list`) on the right. You correctly create an empty list `[]` as the initial state.

When you want to add new key during the folding, you need to pass the existing list (`state`) as the right argument of `::` and the new key (`key`) as the left argument - to create a new list that contains the key as the first element and all remaining elements as the rest (*tail*) of the list.

So 1) the order of arguments for `::` matters and 2) you wanted to collect keys rather than values, but if you were collecting values, it would work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- You do not pass a map but a list.

- state (the result into which your keys are folded) and value (an int) are reversed.

You can either convert your list into a map (see Daniel's comment):

```
["one", 1; "two", 2]
|> Map.ofList
|> Map.fold (fun state key value -> value :: state) [];;
// val it : int list = [2; 1]
```

Alternatively you can fold over a list of tuples:

```
["one", 1; "two", 2]
|> List.fold (fun state (key, value) -> value :: state) [];;
// val it : int list = [2; 1]
```